# How to change the modal popup content based on array of object length using javaScript?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, dom

I have array of object data like below,

```
let loginMessages = [{ NotificationID: 123, NotificationName: "first Message", NotificationDesc: "First Message", ValidFrom: "2019-09-25T00:00:00", ValidTo: "2019-10-03T00:00:00" },
        { NotificationID: 456, NotificationName: "second Message", NotificationDesc: "Second Message", ValidFrom: "2019-09-25T00:00:00", ValidTo: "2019-10-03T00:00:00" }
        ];
```

Here, I displayed the first 123 notification modal popup on page loading. In that first notification modal I have Next button. If we click on Next button, that first popup should override with the second notification data. If the array of object length reached the last item, that time previous button should display.

I don't know how to do this. Please help me.

what I did is,

```
loginMessages.forEach((d) => {
      let listMessag = document.getElementById("modal-content");
      let listTitle = document.getElementById("modal-title");
      $('#infoPopup2').modal('show');
      let el = d.NotificationDesc;
      let ele = d.NotificationName;
      listMessag.innerHTML += el;
      listTitle.innerHTML += ele;
    });

   <div class="modal fade settings-modal" id="infoPopup2" tabindex="-1" role="dialog">
<div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
  <div class="modal-content sp_modal_content auto-height" >
    <div class="modal-header sp_modal_header">
      <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
        <span aria-hidden="true">
          <img class="sp_modal_close_img" src="/images/button_close_small.png">
        </span>
      </button>
      <h4 class="modal-title sp_modal_heading" id="modal-title"> </h4>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-body text-editor-p" id="modal-content">

      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">

        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-sm-12">

            <p class="pull-left">
              <input type='checkbox' store="checkbox3" /> Don't show again
              @*<input type='checkbox' store="checkbox2" />*@


            </p>
          </div>
        </div>

        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-sm-12">

            <button type="button" id="next" class="sp_button sp_login_button pull-left">NEXT</button>
            <p class="pull-right">2/3</p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  <!-- modal-content -->
</div>
```

This is my output,
[image: output]

here, two notifications data displaying in one popup. I need to display the second message popup separately by clicking next button.

Comment: Please create a complete snippet

Comment: `loginMessages.forEach((d) => {` - do what's inside this once, keep a reference to the current index, then when next is clicked, increase index and call again.  You already have all the code you need, just it's in a loop

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were just going through the arrays and displaying the values to html.

Try this. Current index will always show the 1st array, when the showNotification(currentIndex); is called.

Clicking next will increment the index and trigger the showNotification function again, with the index being updated.

```
let loginMessages = [
      { NotificationID: 123, NotificationName: "first Message", NotificationDesc: "First Message", ValidFrom: "2019-09-25T00:00:00", ValidTo: "2019-10-03T00:00:00" },
      { NotificationID: 456, NotificationName: "second Message", NotificationDesc: "Second Message", ValidFrom: "2019-09-25T00:00:00", ValidTo: "2019-10-03T00:00:00" }
    ];
    
    let currentIndex = 0;
    const modal = document.getElementById("modal");
    const nextButton = document.getElementById("nextButton");
    showNotification(currentIndex);
    
    nextButton.addEventListener("click", () => {
      currentIndex++;
      showNotification(currentIndex);
    });
    
    function showNotification(index) {
      const messages = loginMessages[index];
      modal.innerHTML = 
        `<p>ID: ${messages.NotificationID}</p>
        <p>Name: ${messages.NotificationName}</p>
        <p>Description: ${messages.NotificationDesc}</p>
        <p>Valid from: ${messages.ValidFrom}</p>
        <p>Valid to: ${messages.ValidTo}</p>
      `;
    }
```

Comment: @freedomn-m If I click on Do not show again checkbox, that time particular object should remove. How can I achieve this? please give me suggestion

Comment: You'll get a better response if you ask a new question, including your updated code, possibly linking back to this question/answer.

Comment: @user18513197 One way to do is to store a user specific value in local storage, so you know if you should show them this or not. It really depends on what this message is and your project.